# How to load a pdf received from an http call into the viewer?

Tags: javascript, pdf, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am getting a pdf from:

`return this.http.get(path, { observe: 'response', responseType: 'arraybuffer' });`

and processing it as a blob:

`let blob: Blob = new Blob([response.body], { type: 'application/pdf' });`

I am now looking to store that file locally and reference it through a local url. The reason I need to use a url is because the `viewer.loadModel()` requires it as a parameter. I have tried using `let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.blobToFile(blob, 'viewer.pdf'));` to get a url.

When i do that I get: `https://localhost:3000/35ef3b8e-e59f-4fe9-a8cc-1e2e542ffb2a`
The viewer doesn't know the file type without the '*.pdf*' behind it though. If I put .pdf behind that url: `https://localhost:3000/35ef3b8e-e59f-4fe9-a8cc-1e2e542ffb2a.pdf`, it seems to load some data but I get the following error:

```
core.js:6241 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined
    at v (Viewer3D.js:1335)
    at PDFLoader.js:1358
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:386)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:41697)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:385)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:143)
    at zone.js:891
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41675)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:832)
    at zone.js:739
    at zone.js:755
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:386)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:41697)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:385)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:143)
    at zone.js:891
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41675)
```

which is on the last line below: (Viewer3D.js:1335)

```
Viewer3D.prototype.loadModel = async function(url, options, onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback, onWorkerStart) {
        var self = this;

        // Kind of sucks, but I couldn't think of a better way because loaders
        // are so
        var reservation = self.impl._reserveLoadingFile();     // Reserve a slot for a loading file
        options = options || {};

        if (typeof options.skipPropertyDb === "undefined") {
            var skipParam = getParameterByName("skipPropertyDb") || "";
            options.skipPropertyDb = skipParam === "true" ? true : (skipParam === "false" ? false : undefined);
        }

        var loaderInstance;
        function onDone( error, model ) {
            self.impl._removeLoadingFile(loaderInstance);
            if (error) {
                self.dispatchEvent({ type: et.LOADER_LOAD_ERROR_EVENT, error: error, loader: loaderInstance })
                onError( error.code, error.msg, error.args );
                return;
            }

            model.getData().underlayRaster = options.underlayRaster && model.getLeaflet();
```

Is there a way I can store the pdf locally from the blob and then get a local URL to it that will work with it? Or is there a way I can pass a bearer token so the loader can access storage? I'm not sure what else to do because the viewer.loadModel() only seems to work if I use a local absolute path to a file (Ex. https://localhost:3000/Content/Documents/qcad1.pdf"). I'd also like to mention I can't process it through the model-derivative api as it loses the pdf vectors if I do.

More context:
This is where I'm loading the model...

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({ env: 'Local' }, () => {
            this.viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('forgeViewer'));
            this.viewer.start();
            this.viewer.setTheme('dark-theme');
            this.viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore');

            this.viewer.loadModel(this.pdfUrl, {}, this.initializeMeasureSettings.bind(this),
                () => {
                    console.log('File could not be loaded');

                    // On error was hoping to load a sample model but it loses context to the viewer somehow
                    //this.viewer.loadModel(this.samplePDF, {}, this.initializeMeasureSettings);
                });

            this.viewer.addEventListener('measurement-changed', this.onMeasurementChanged.bind(this));
            this.viewer.addEventListener('measurement-completed', this.onMeasurementCompleted.bind(this));
            this.viewer.addEventListener('finished-calibration', this.onCalibrationFinished.bind(this));
            this.viewer.addEventListener('delete-measurement', this.onObjectDeleted.bind(this));
            this.viewer.addEventListener('extensionLoaded', this.extensionLoaded.bind(this));

        });
```

Comment: Just to double-check, why exactly are you downloading the PDF first and *then* trying to turn it into a URL on the client? Is it because the original PDF address is protected?

Comment: Yes exactly. If i try to access our files through a regular URL it requires a bearer token from the client and there's no way to pass that to the viewer.loadModel(). So my idea was to download the actual data to the browser and get a reference to it as above.. doesn't seem to be working though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up going deep into the pdfLoader and I found a way to pass a bearer token down which is used by PDFJS when loading the file from a url!

Just before calling `viewer.loadModel` I set:

`` Autodesk.Viewing.endpoint.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS = { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authenticationService.getToken}` }; ``

This is accessed PDFLoader.js:749 `params.httpHeaders = av.endpoint.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS;`.

This params object is what ends up being passed into `PDFJS.getDocument(params)` in the Promise.resolve (line 1370).

It's a standard feature in pdf.js but maybe Autodesk could make it easier by allowing it to be passed in the options object in viewer.loadModel().

Anyways, this allows me to download files securely from the backend and load them into the viewer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the `loadModel` method does not support any way to specify custom HTTP request headers so if the access to your PDF file is protected with an access token, that will be tricky.

What you could try is "hacking" the logic inside the `loadModel` function, not by appending `.pdf` directly to the data URI, but by faking the extension in a URL query or hash, e.g.:

`https://localhost:3000/35ef3b8e-e59f-4fe9-a8cc-1e2e542ffb2a?name=foo.pdf`

or

`https://localhost:3000/35ef3b8e-e59f-4fe9-a8cc-1e2e542ffb2a#foo.pdf`

This *might* be enough to convince the viewer to use the PDF loader, and at the same time it won't break the meaning of the URL.

Comment: I tried that and it got through to grab the PDF loader but it still failed with the error from above

Comment: Ok, I just noticed something in your code snippet. You don't seem to be loading the `Autodesk.PDF` extension anywhere in there. I'm not sure if loading a PDF without it works the same, but just to be sure, activate the extension before loading your PDFs (as explained in https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/fast-pdf-viewingmarkup-inside-forge-viewer).

Comment: Right I had been doing that, but it worked without it with the local file so I figured maybe I don't need it.

Comment: I see... I'm afraid that there's some additional checks in the PDF loader that assume the URL to be a proper, server-side URL, not a data URI.

Comment: In that case, the only workaround I can think about is having some kind of a proxy that can attach your access token to the request the PDF loader makes when loading a PDF document, for example, using service workers, or perhaps by exposing one more endpoint by your server backend, where the PDF can be accessed (temporarily) without any access token.

Comment: So we tried it and proxies don't work in a pre-compiled angular site. yay. I'm going to see if i can load the pdf into the viewer manually. If you have any ideas i'd be happy to hear them

Comment: Figured out a way! See the answer if you're interested